# OSX Lion, replaced hard drive & can't open TrueCrypt volume: permission denied

Tags: osx-lion, truecrypt

I have an external drive with a TrueCrypt volume. I recently replaced my **internal** HD and am now unable to open/mount the external TrueCrypt volume. TC returns a simple "permission denied" error. I am absolutely certain I am using the correct password.
Is there any sort of key exchange with a TC volume that I may have lost when I reformatted my internal drive? Could permissions be an issue?

Comment: It sounds like a permissions issue. TC is very portable (I use it across linux, OS X, and Windows 7/XP). How is the TC container set up? Is is the whole drive or a container file on the drive? Are you trying to mount it to a device that already exists?

Comment: It's a container file, with a second hidden container inside of it. I'm opening it (as I usually have in the past) by opening TrueCrypt, selecting my TC container, clicking Mount and then answering the password prompt. I'll double-check permissions.